# Asked in an interview: Dynamic Programming

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

"N" bombs are kept in a line. Each bomb has an "index" corresponding to it. Say the i-th position bomb has index as k. It means that when the i-th bomb is diffused, it diffuses along with the k bombs to its left and k bombs to its right are also diffused. First line of input contains the number N(number of bombs), next line contains space separated bomb index(k). Print the output as the minimum number of such bombs which when diffused diffuses all other bombs, followed by the bomb index(s). If there are more than one such combination of index, print them on separate lines.

eg

Input:

8

1 2 7 3 4 9 3 4

Output

1

9

Input:

20

1 1 1 9 1 1 1 1 1 4 1 1 1 1 1 8 1 1 1 1

Output

2

9 8

Comment: You meant to post this on your blog. Stack Overflow is for **questions**.

Comment: Yes, I can't think of a solution for this. It was asked in an online round. Can anyone help me with the algorithm?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes, Once I get a logic for the solution, I would definitely post it on my blog ;) , and as you said Stack Overflow is for Questions.

Comment: The output is a little confusing. The input numbers are not distinct, but you're asked to print at least one of them? How will you know which one the output refers to?

Comment: @IVlad I don't have the exact question, I wrote the question as much as I remembered. Could you help me getting the minimum of such bombs? Leave printing the index.

Answer (score 1):

Let:

```
dp[i] = minimum number of bombs that need to be defused in order to defuse
        all bombs in [1, i] considering only bombs in [1, i]
```

We have:

```
dp[anything<=0] = 0
dp[1] = 1 <- must defuse the first bomb
dp[k] = min{dp[k - a[k]] + overlap, <- if the current bomb also defuses
                                       a[k] to its left and right, then we can just 
                                       defuse that and reduce the problem 
                                       to defusing bombs [1, k - a[k]]
            dp[k - a[k] + 1] + overlap, <- same reasoning; some overlaps might provide
                                           a better solution
            dp[k - a[k] + 2] + overlap,
            ...
            dp[k - 1] + overlap}
```

Where `overlap` is `1` if the the bomb at `p = k - a[k] + i` does not also defuse the `k`-th bomb and `0` otherwise.

Answer will be `dp[n]`. A direct implementation is `O(n^2)`. It might be possible to make this linear.

Worked example:

```
a = 1 2 7 3 4 9 3 4
dp[1] = 1
dp[2] = min{dp[2 - 2] + 1,
            dp[2 - 1] + 0 (because the first bomb also defuses this one}
      = 1
dp[3] = min{dp[3 - 7] + 1,
            dp[3 - 2] + 1 (because the first bomb does not also defuse this one),
            dp[3 - 1] + 0}
      = 1
...
```

Comment: could you explain your answer a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an endless supply of dynamic programming questions in which there are things arranged in a line and you can solve them by working from left to right, using previously computed partial solutions at each step.

Here you can think about keeping track of a sorted array that gives you the least cost way of covering the first i positions - what this cost is, what the rightmost bomb is in the sequence that achieves this cost. As i increases the least cost will increase, because if there is a cheaper way to cover n>m positions than m positions, you can use that solution to cover m positions as well and throw away the answer for m positions. I say a sorted array but a standard tree/SortedMap will probably be better.

At stage i where you have costs to cover everything up to at least the i-1th position look at the index k there and combine this with the best way of covering the first i-k positions to see if this gives you a cheaper (or the only way so far) of covering the first i+k. If so, update the data structure to record this answer.

When you have done all the positions look for the cheapest way to cover all the positions and see what the last bomb used was. Then look to see the rightmost index that bomb leaves uncovered and look to see the cheapest way to cover at least as far as that to find the next bomb to use - and so on.